# Get number of TCP established connections

Tags: linux, monitoring, tcp, netstat

On a Linux server one can use `netstat -tan | grep ESTABLISHED| wc -l` but this will not work on a high load server with `watch -n1`.

Such approach works fine if the server is not very busy or the monitoring interval is big enough.  But what can be recommended as alternative for a high load server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of (currently) established TCP connections for a specific port?](http://serverfault.com/questions/527875/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-currently-established-tcp-connections-for-a-specifi)

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you mean you want an update more often than every 1 second?  Or you want to know the total number of connections that were established during some period, instead of the number of connections that are established at the moment you run netstat?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman on high load,`netstat` followed by a `grep` command will not be fast enough to give statistics in order of seconds. But you can get it with `ss` or parsing `/proc`.

I want to know the number of TCP established connections each second.

Comment: seomthing like a diff of the output of ss over time ?

Comment: @Sirex in fact in my case I just wanted to watch it over time. If you are goint to script something I would prefer `[cat/sed/grep]` in `/proc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using /proc to reduce workload

I like to access *kernel variables* directly through `/proc`. This is very efficient, quick and system friendly.

There is a pseudo file (kernel variables table) named `/proc/net/tcp` where
kernel store list of TCP connection and listenning. The 6th field, called *`st`* for *state* could contain `0A` for a listen entry and `01` for an established connection.

Counting **TCP  *established*** connections:

By using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
grep </proc/net/tcp -c '^ *[0-9]\+: [0-9A-F: ]\{27\} 01 '
```

By using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk  </proc/net/tcp 'BEGIN{t=0};{if ($4 == "01") {t++;}};END{print t}'
```

or

```
awk  </proc/net/tcp 'BEGIN{t=0};/^ *[0-9]+: [0-9A-F: ]{27} 01 /{t++};END{print t}'
```

By using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed  </proc/net/tcp '/^ *[0-9]\+: [0-9A-F: ]\{27\} 01 /p;d' | wc -l
```

#### Execution time

As this question stand for high workload system. I've done a little bench:

```
Method                                Answer by     Milliseconds

grep                                  Techno        2.48
awk no regexp ($4=="01")                            2.51
sed | wc                                            2.67
awk with regexp                                     2.93

ss -neopt state established | wc -l   Suprjami     15.14
lsof -i tcp -s tcp:ESTABLISHED        Tonioc    25055.00
```

Ok Tonioc's answer is very slow, but very insteresting by his verbosity. So clearly not useable on high workload system.

This bench let you see that if `ss` is a very usefull dedicated tool, asking `/proc` variables could be a lot quicker.

Comment: Is it just me or does `/proc/net/tcp` not show port numbers?

Comment: Or are they after the colon in hex?

Comment: @KenSharp Yes, it is. 1st line is header line. fields `local_address` and `rem_address` do contain IP and PORT separated by colon. field `st` (status) make difference between ESTABLISHED, LISTEN, WAIT ...

Comment: +1 for time comparission! And yes, for just counting *established tcp connection*, using `ss` or any `netstat` is overkill, when `/proc/net/tcp/` present what you need!

Comment: For *socket stats* you could read `cat /proc/net/sockstat*` ! Could be more quicker!!

Answer (score 7):

Use the command:

```
ss -neopt state established
```

This will show you only TCP sessions in `ESTABLISHED` state, no piping to other commands required, so it's super fast.

`ss` is better than `netstat` because the older `netstat` just reads from procfs which is subject to file locks. `ss` actually makes a query inside the kernel which is handled by the kernel scheduler and always returns accurate information.

Comment: Uh? FS ***procfs*** mounted in `/proc` is a ***pseudo file system***! Subject to ***lockfile***??? Please post references! At my knowledge, this pseudo filesystem is just a way to access kernel variables!

Comment: Then try: `strace ss -neopt state established 2>&1 | grep proc/`...

Comment: procfs writes line by line. If you have many many open connections, like hundreds of thousands, the earlier stuff is outdated by the time you get to the end. It's a waste of time. ss netlink gets the current state from the kernel at one point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Check also: [527875](https://serverfault.com/questions/527875/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-currently-established-tcp-connections-for-a-specifi).

`netstat + grep` is a good and simple option for a few connections but if you have a huge number of connections I would recommend `ss` as recommended in [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-investigate-sockets-network-connections.html).

For instance: `ss -s`

```
Total: 78 (kernel 79)
TCP:   31 (estab 27, closed 0, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 16

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*     79        -         -        
RAW   0         0         0        
UDP   4         2         2        
TCP   31        2         29       
INET      35        4         31       
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Answer (score 2):

`ss` is a good tool. For kicks you could also can just:

```
[kbrandt@ny-kbrandt01: ~] cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Tcp | awk '{print $10}'
CurrEstab
3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also lsof, which can filter per protocol and state: for example to look for TCP ESTABLISHED connections:

```
~# lsof -i tcp -s tcp:ESTABLISHED
```

then | wc -l to count. 
Note: did not try the cost of this with a huge number of connections.

Comment: U could add `-n` in `lsof -ni` to prevent DNS resolution and make this a lot quicker!